# How to use SSMA (for Access to SQL Server) to migrate a table with different columns into a existing table?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi

I am currently using Microsoft SSMA to migrate tables from my old Access database into an existing SQL Server. The two databases have exactly the same tables but one of the tables has an extra column. SSMA is returning an error for one of the table during migration complaining that the data type is not matching as the columns are actually aligning.

For example, table in Access where `Col1` and `Col3` are both `datetime`:

```
ID Col1 Col3
```

Table in SQL Server: `Col2` is double and `Col1/Col3` are still datetime

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3
```

Is there a way to get the tables to migrate Access data successfully into existing table (without overwriting the table)?

P.S. I am using the command-line script to run SSMA

Comment: If it is one time task then export the table to `excel` or `csv` file, then import that excel file to `SQL` database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SQL Server's datetime has more options/variations and can/may differ than Access'... look more deeply into exactly the definition of the syntax/format  of the datetime property for both...

am not sure whether or not you need to add Col2 to the Access table; you don't indicate this is the cause so assuming your SQL Col2 will accept null...